# How do I add an SVG line over a css style

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, d3.js

How do I make an SVG line appear on top of a css style element.  So in my html file I have an svg white background created in javascript using d3.  On top of that I'm putting in these css stylized rectangles, and then on top of those I want to put svg lines also created in javascript that go over the svg rectangles. The problem is that the lines keep appearing behind the css rectangles.  Any suggestions?  I create the white background using d3 like so:

```
var vizSVG = d3.select("#viz")
                    .append("svg:svg")
                    .attr("width",page_width)
                    .attr("height",page_height)
```

And I create the css rectangles inside an html style element like so:

```
<style>
                rectangle{
                    border-radius: 8px;
                    width:20%;
                    height:32px;
                    text-indent:10px;
                    padding-top:20px;
                    padding-left:12px;
                    font-family: Courier, Bold, sans-serif;
                    font-size: 13px;
                    display: block;
                    }
</style>
```

Finally I want to also add the svg lines using d3 like so:

```
vizSVG.append("line")
    .attr("x1",0)
    .attr("y1",0)
    .attr("x2",1000)
    .attr("y2",1000)
    .style("stroke", "black")
    .style("stroke-width", 150)
    .attr("stroke-linecap","round");
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to append the elements in the order you want them to appear in, back element first.

Comment: I did, I added the line element last inside the javascript tags, after I created the css rectangles, but the line appears behind the rectangles.  Is there something I could do involving appendChild to ensure the lines go on top.

Comment: I've also tried appending the lines to the rectangles themselves but they don't appear on top, is that because they're created in css?

Comment: Ah ok, your rectangles are HTML and not in the SVG? In that case, there's no way -- the SVG is one layer as far as HTML is concerned. You could split it up into separate SVGs or draw the rectangles in the SVG as well.

Comment: The code inside the style tags isn't css but html?  What do you mean by split it up into separate SVGs? Also, is it possible to append one layer on top of the other or effect the order in which layers are displayed?

Comment: Are the rectangles you are creating part of the SVG?

Comment: Have you tried some combination of z-Index Attributes ? E.g. Add a negative value to the CSS for Elements in the Background and a positive value to the uppermost SVG Element/Container

Answer (score 0):

changing the z-index in the css code helped although I have to find out how to change the z-index for my svg tags to put the right elements on top.  Thanks to those who answered

Dante

Comment: SVG has no concept of z-index.